# Select data from two different tables, count and distribute daily

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select data from two different tables. The data and count distribuilos per day, for example:

```
customers | sales | date
5         |   5   | 2014-11-01
0         |   2   | 2014-11-02
1         |   0   | 2014-11-03
0         |   0   | 2014-11-04
```

and continues until the end of the month

I started to select that way, but do not know how to search in every day and do not want to put in a loop to perform multiple searches on bench

```
  SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers) AS customers, 
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales) AS sales 
  FROM dual
```

Comment: your question is not clear, can you explain better/more ?

Comment: I think you should start by specifying what your table structure is, because from what you posted, it seems impossible to know.

Comment: Hello! I would like to do a select data which I do a search for day two tables, telling amount customers who signed up that day and there were also sales on the same day, sorry, do not know if I explained well. It would be something like: "select count (*) from customers WHERE date = '2014-11-01'" But for every day without putting in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a date column in each table, you can come close with:

```
select date, sum(customers) as customers, sum(sales) as sales
from ((select date, count(*) as customers, 0 as sales
       from customers
       where date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30'
       group by date
      ) union all
      (select date, 0 as customers, count(*) as sales
       from sales
       where date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30'
       group by date
      )
     ) cs
group by date
order by date;
```

This will give you all dates that are in either table.  To get all the dates, even those with no data, you need a table of the dates or a way to generate them.  Here is one way, assuming you have a calendar table:

```
select date, sum(customers) as customers, sum(sales) as sales
from ((select date, 0 as customers, 0 as sales
       from calendar
       where date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30'
      ) union all
      (select date, count(*) as customers, 0 as sales
       from customers
       where date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30'
       group by date
      ) union all
      (select date, 0 as customers, count(*) as sales
       from sales
       where date between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30'
       group by date
      )
     ) dcs
group by date
order by date;
```